# Обособление сочетания "согласно данным"

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в данном случае верно и почему?

"В статье широкий интерес к проекту объясняется тем, что, согласно данным бирж, трейдеры прибывают со всех уголков страны, включая отдаленные города"

"В статье широкий интерес к проекту объясняется тем, что согласно данным бирж трейдеры прибывают со всех уголков страны, включая отдаленные города"

Answer (score 3):

Обособление с предлогом "согласно" является факультативным. Обычно не обособляются оборот, если он входит в состав сказуемого(такой оборот нельзя убрать из предложения без потери смысла).

Пример:

```
Он действовал согласно правилам.
```

Если оборот можно изять из предложения, то обособление зависит от интонации, степени распространности оборота,от порядка слов в предложении. Обычно такой оборот обособляется обороты, если стоит между подлежащим и сказуемым, в середине предложения.

> Поэтому, согласно вышеуказанной статье Налогового Кодекса, прошу произвести перерасчет налоговой базы.

В вашем предложении оборот стоит в середине предложение, поэтому обособление корректно.

[Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1)

Answer (score 1):

Правильно первое (с обособлением). Из Розенталя:

> Запятыми выделяются **вводные слова**, указывающие на **источник сообщения**:
>   *говорят, сообщают, передают, по словам.., по сообщению.., по сведениям.., по мнению.., по-моему, по-твоему, по-нашему, по-вашему,
>   на мой взгляд, с точки зрения, по слухам, по преданию, помнится,
>   слышно, дескать, как говорят, как пишут, как известно и др.*

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm